# Unable to add click event to a cloned object using jquery

Tags: jquery, binding, onclick, onclicklistener, jquery-clone

Below is the sample code which i was trying to attach a click event to the cloned object but i couldn't do that i have tried a lot but i couldn't attach the click event to the object. Please check the code and give your valuable suggestions

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var documentSelector = $('.clone-block')
    var arrayOfObjects = [{
     name: "William", 
        gender: "Male",
        dateofbirth: "01-01-2017"
    }, 
    {
     name: "Michale", 
        gender: "Female",
        dateofbirth: "01-01-2018"
    }, 
    { 
     name: "John", 
        gender: "male",
        dateofbirth: "01-01-2019"
    },
    {
     name: "tom", 
        gender: "male",
        dateofbirth: "01-01-2020"
    }];
    
    $.each(arrayOfObjects, function (ind, user){
     var clonedObject = documentSelector.clone(true, true);       
        clonedObject.find('span').on('click', alertWhenClicked.bind(user));
        clonedObject.find('span').text(user.name);
        $('.link-p').append(clonedObject.html());
    });
    
    function alertWhenClicked () {
     alert(this.dateofbirth);
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="clone-block" >
 <p>Username : <span></span></p>
</div>
<div class="link-p" ></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.link-p').append(clonedObject.html());
```

You are turning the object into html and that is being appended to the dom, which will not have any of the event bindings on it.  Take off the `.html()`

As an aside note, you should look into delegate bindings so you don't have to put an event binding on all these elements.

```
$.each(arrayOfObjects, function (ind, user){
    var clonedObject = documentSelector.clone(true, true);
    //put the user on the element as a data object for easy reference
    clonedObject.data('user', user);
    clonedObject.find('span').text(user.name);
    $('.link-p').append(clonedObject);
});

//delegate bind the click event to the parent for the future child elements
$('.link-p').on('click', '.clone-block', alertWhenClicked);

function alertWhenClicked () {
    alert($(this).data('user').dateofbirth);
}
```